# Joining tables in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hey I'm very new to rails and would appreciate the help greatly!

Every user has a profile page that shows all of his events. Every event has many assets (images). And every event also has its own event page. What I'm struggling with is how to display the events (if they exist) on the user profile page and do the join.

In my profile controller i have : @events = User.joins(:events) to get the events but I then need to drill into the assets table to get the relevant image (for now I just want to grab any image that's there for that event, later i'll add a "main picture" flag).

Here are my models.

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event
has_attached_file :image,
:styles => {
  :thumb=> "100x100#",
  :small  => "300x300>",
  :large => "600x600>"
    },
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
  :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
  :bucket => 'wpt-assets'
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :budget, :client, :date, :description, :venue, :attendees,  
:assets_attributes
belongs_to :user
has_many :assets#, :dependent => destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
rolify
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,  
:remember_me,:avatar, :bio, :title, :company,:facebook,:twitter,:pinterest,:linkedin
validates_presence_of :username
validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email, :case_sensitive => false
has_many :events
has_attached_file :avatar, 
:styles => { 
  :medium => "100x100>", 
  :thumb => "24x24>" }

  def to_param
    username
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The first query, to get the `Event`s for a `User`, can just be written as

```
@events = user.events
```

Similarly, you can get all `Assets` for an `Event` with `event.assets`.

The [Rails Guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) documents this in more detail, but you usually don't have to use the `join` method unless you're doing something more advanced.

Comment: That makes sense and worked. Now I'm trying to display one of the images associated with each event like this: 
<% @events.each do |e| %>
<%= image_tag e.assets.first.path %>

path is the field in the assets table that contains the image path.